# Asymptotic expression for a fraction

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

Assume that $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ with $x>y+1$.

Moreoever, let $v=v(x,y)$ and $w=w(x,y)$ with $w(x,y)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Let
$$
x-y=\frac{\ln(1+v)}{\ln(1+w)}
$$
and assume that $x-y$ is constant. Does this imply that
$$
v\sim w\textrm{ as }x\to\infty?
$$

Intuitively, I think that this is correct, since if the fraction is constant, then $v$ should "behave as $w$".

---

In order to actually prove the statement, I have to show that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{v}{w}=1.$$

I do not get that but setting $C:=x-y$, I get
$$
x-y=\frac{\ln(1+v)}{\ln(1+w)}\Leftrightarrow (1+v)=(1+w)^C\Leftrightarrow v=(1+w)^C-1
$$
so that
$$
\frac{v}{w}=\frac{(1+w)^C}{w}-\frac{1}{w}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $v\sim w$ as $x\to\infty$ is in general not true. More specifically,  with l'Hospital,
$$
\frac{v}{w}=\frac{(1+w)^C-1}{w}\to C\quad \textrm{ as } x\to\infty
$$
so the limit of the fraction needs not to be $1$ in general.

However,what you get is that $v\in O(w)$ as $x\to\infty$.